# Migrating angular 1.6 and angular 5

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to migrate angular1.6 and angular5.

My question:

1. Without changing angular1.6 code and new angular 5 code run simultaneously?
2. How to define the code structure for this?
3. How to grunt these angular1.6 and angular5 code?

Requirement :

Because i need to run application angular1.6 and angular5 independently.

Please give some example to solve this

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand what you mean by running it simultaneously ... please clarify on that. It sure is possible to migrate and you can search for and read many post of people trying to do so. There is even some official advice available [@angular.io](https://angular.io/guide/upgrade) ... but from my personal experience, I would not do that. Use AngularJS version as a mockup and refactor it freshly into Angular5+ ... it is a tedious job to upgrade from AngularJS 1.6 to Angular5. Can be done, but per my opinion it is not good approach. Learn from what was bad about your AngularJS and try make it better in Angular5, step by step.

Comment: Ok but..it will affect exisiting business. And need to do code in angular 1 and angular 5 in same project.

Comment: What do you mean by 'need to do code in angular 1 and angular 5 in same project'? Is it that you are worried that you have to code the same project twice once in AngularJS and then in Angular5? Or that you somehow intend  to use code written in AngularJS and Angular5 simultaneously? First is inevitable since AngularJS is pretty dead. Second is near to impossible and kind of irrational.

Comment: Ok . but we are doing angular 5 in one part of team. but other teams are using angular 1. In that scenario what we do?

Comment: Ask you PM. I know nothing about the product and your goals, I truly cannot help. As far I can see, AngularJS is not viable, if you built corporate system on that AJS or some platform specific commercial product, I would argue that it was not a good business decision -> that seems so crazy as the projects you can see still running around saying "Works only in IE6 on Win XP" -> AngularJS is soon to be forgotten I am afraid. And from coding point of view, I would not be happy working with AngularJS (I did some three years ago and I am glad I did not ever since, but I like Angular5+).